# Performance testing using JMeter

Tags: ajax, extjs, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am writing a test in JMeter for our web app, but there is one page that loads and then makes an Ajax call using extjs libraries to load an additional piece, and I need to know when that piece loads.  How should I go about doing this? can JMeter support extjs libraries?  What else do I need to know?

Searching the internet I've found some ajax and JMeter resources and a few extjs and JMeter sources, but I have yet to find all three in one place.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google Chrome has excellent profiling tools built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter's HTTP request works at HTTP protocol level. It [knows nothing](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterFAQ#Does_JMeter_process_dynamic_pages_.28e.g._Javascript_and_applets.29) about your JS and ajax. However, it can send any http requests, including ajax one.

So you should look what requests sends browser when you do something involving Ext JS and create such requests in JMeter. To do it you can use [HTTP Proxy Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Proxy_Server) or look in Firebug or similar thing in your browser.

**Note:** actually JMeter supports Javascript execution through BSF support (look e.g. at [BSF Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_Sampler)). However, it will make your test slower so I think it will be better not to use it

Comment: Which one would make the test slower? BSF Sampler?