# Jmeter - Performance test

Tags: performance, jmeter

I want to load test my web site.
I can extract all http requests from the site and put it on J meter.
But the page have alot more things(like ajax calls)
How can i load test my site (find complete page load time)

Comment: check similar questions on Ajax. probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366171/performance-testing-using-jmeter this will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

I'd go the route of capturing the AJAX calls as past of your script - you have two options:

The JMeter proxy:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

BlazeMeter's JMeter chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi/details?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter is Server side load testing tool and though client is using ajax still http request will be sent to server which will be recorded/scripted in jmeter and thus load testing can be carried out.

please check similar questions on jmeter

check this also 
http://jmetertips.blogspot.in/2009/04/ajax-testing-with-jmeter.html